# How to align text in the box in HTML so that it does not affect the spacing on each side

Tags: html, text, alignment, cell, document-body

I am a newbie in HTML and currently working on my University project work and I really need some help. I am using a background box for the "blog-like" website which needs to align title and short text on the left and contents with hyperlinks on the right.

So far I have used a cell to align them but to say the least, it looks very ugly and moreover affects spacing. No matter what I tried I can't change the contents on both sides without a response from another. Is it possible to arrange content somehow another way instead of using a single cell for an entire box and dividing percentage for each side? I have uploaded a picture of the website below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <title>
      Your Personal Guide To Best Hardcore Events
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        background: url(http://webprojects.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/at315/background.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-attachment: fixed
      }

      .background {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      div.transbox {
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1.5px solid black;
        opacity: 0.6;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60);
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1300px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p align="center">
      <img src="http://webprojects.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/at315/header.png" style="width:70%;" border="0" alt="" />
    </p>
    <div class="background">
      <div class="transbox">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <th width="75%" align="left">
              <h2>
                    Articles:
                  </h2>
            </th>
            <th width="20%" align="center">
              <ul style="list-style: none;">
                <li>
                  <a href="http://webprojects.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/rr305/CourseWork/blog.xml" style="text-decoration:none">Homepage</a>
                  <br />
                  <br />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <small><a href="http://www.qmul.ac.uk" style=
                      "text-decoration:none">Architects</a></small>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <small><a href="https://www.facebook.com" style=
                      "text-decoration:none">Northlane</a></small>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <small><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk" style=
                      "text-decoration:none">Attila</a></small>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left">
              <h4>
                    <strong>Architects Rocking Brixton</strong>
                  </h4>Read our article about Architects headlining their biggest sold-out UK show!
              <hr />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left">
              <h4>
                    <strong>Architects Rocking Brixton</strong>
                  </h4>Read our article about Architects headlining their biggest sold-out UK show!
              <hr />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left">
              <h4>
                    <strong>Architects Rocking Brixton</strong>
                  </h4>Read our article about Architects headlining their biggest sold-out UK show!
              <br />
              <br />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Main page of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy1TQ.jpg)

Comment: Your HTML code seems somehow broken, I tried to format it, and I found tags not closed, you are closing `ul` without open it, the code really does not make sense, you want to review it and fix the code, the not ended tags or incorrect endings surely will break out the layout.

Comment: Please See the updated code, I have just updated it.

Comment: Dear @alexander. What you currently want is another question. I answered you first question and it was better to ask this as a new question.(and of course check me answer as true :-P)

Comment: Sorry about it, yes you have helped a lot sir

Comment: Dear Farzin, thank you for your advice, unfortunately due to me being registrated here for a short period of time I can't submit any more questions for 4 days, so I can't do so :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situations it is best to use flex and max width. It is very good to responsive design so.

```
.background {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

div.transbox {
margin: 30px;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid black;
opacity: 0.6;
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
width: 100%;
max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Change your browser size, It work good for all sizes. And the best part is if the screen has width < 1000px the table fills all of the screen.

Comment: This is a great advice, thank you! I've just tried and it resizes perfectly! But I still can't overcome a problem with aligning text properly inside this box as if I create a cell that covers 100% of it and divide it into 2 parts in order to align content to the left and to the right, as soon as the spacing of the content on the right increases like it could be seen with a mini menu with hyperlinks, then the spacing between header i.e "Articles" and the subheading and text increases as well, is there a way to deal with it? Thank you

Comment: Sorry but i did not understand what you said. I read that 2 times. Could you please explain clearly?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, by the way as been stated in the main comment sections, I had a multiple of errors, I have fixed them now, so you might want to see the updated code. The problem I have, as you could see I have 3 elements background and header which are separate images and then i have a content box in the front. What I had trouble doing is aligning text correctly in it. The view should be blog-like, i.e Left top is heading which is "Articles" and then articles are listed below. The problem I have is spacing, as it is a single cell, as content on the right side takes more space than

Comment: left side, it cause the left side to move proportionally, causing unnecessary space being created

Comment: Is it possible to make them separated elements so that a change in one would not affect the position of another

Comment: Dear @aleksander: I set a name for you top image id="imgTop" then add this style:#imgTop{width:70%; height:120px; }and it is like you want

Comment: Thank you very much your help is so much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

just change this tag:

```
<table style="padding:0 5% " width = "90%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)